# Is it sufficient to integrate over a subset of probability 1 to compute the expectation?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega,F,\mathbb{P})$ and a random variable $X:\Omega\to\Omega'(=\mathbb{R}?)$. Does it hold in general that for every subset $O\subseteq\Omega$ such that $\mathbb{P}(O)=1$ we have that
$$\int_O X\,d\mathbb{P}=\int_\Omega X\, d\mathbb{P}=E(X)?$$
The reason I'm asking this was because I was asked to compute the expectation of a discrete random variable which could attain the value $+\infty$ with probability $0$. I claimed that it sufficed to compute the expectation over a subset with probability $1$ where the random variable did attain finite values, but I'm actually not sure if this is legit. Intuitively I would say the expectation is undefined if we allow cases of $\infty\cdot0$, so I'm thinking that it's a matter of convention, but I would like to have a more rigorous answer for this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and $(\infty).(0)=0$ by convention, so $\int_{O^{c}} XdP=0$.

Comment: If you flip a fair coin until you get heads,  you are almost sure (probability $1$) that you will first flip heads in a finite number of flips.  You can then find the expected number of flips is $2$, and not worry about the probability $0$ event that you take an infinite number of flips.